# Docker and certificates not trusted with-in rider only

Tags: docker, docker-compose, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am wanting to continue using Rider IDE but I am having some issue now that we have switched to using docker to host a local image of the client and API for our application due to needing an offline state of holding inputted and stored data. So when we switched to using docker I used visual studio to start out on working with docker and have no issue running a docker compose in visual studio at all. Now then switching back over to Rider I can start the client with now issues exposing 443 and 80, but with out API we do not expose port 443 but running the compose file I get a Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.

[image: Cert Error]